# height and vertical position are ambiguous for UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uistackview

Autolayout cannot figure out the height or vertical position of a UIStackView despite having added subviews.

This is a pretty common error and "gotcha" so please see the answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If this is for a UIStackView make sure you are using `addArrangedSubview` and **not** `addSubview`

Answer (score 3):

For me I received the following error:

`warning: Ambiguous Layout: Position and size are ambiguous for 'Button'.`

Where the button was placed inside a stack view in Interface Builder. The problem was that I had checked "Hidden" in Interface Builder which meant Xcode was freaking out saying position and size are ambiguous. Just **uncheck "Hidden" on the stack view** and the warning will disappear... Magic! ✨

Answer (score 0):

As of XCode 12.3, you can control drag from your S`tackView` to your `View` which will allow you to create constraints to resolve the warning:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2813.jpg

This will bring up this window which is helpful if you want to deal with leading/trailing space issues or centering:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdiBZ.jpg